# The client with object id does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/read' over scope

Tags: azure, api, authentication

I am using Azure app service api to view server details like worker process and region etc. for management purpose. After generating token from **AuthenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync** method, I am requesting following URL for server details **https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<sub ID>/resourceGroups/<resource group name>/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/?api-version=2018-02-01**

In the response I am getting **AuthorizationFailed** error code with the detail given bellow:

> The client does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/read' over scope '/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxx/resourceGroups/xxxxxxxxxxx/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/xxxx' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials.

But when I try the same verification using **https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/appserviceenvironments/get** portal where I can try the APIs for testing, the request is returning expected results.

So, is there any other way to authenticate or should I have to define some permissions to achieve the functionality?

Comment: The app you are using for authentication should have the necessary RBAC roles set in the Access Control (IAM) tab of the resource, resource group, or subscription.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The service principal you are using doesn't have rights within that tenant.

Tenants have subscriptions and service principals belong to tenants. Azure resource manager also exposes role based authorization for a given principal, which would give it rights on Azure resources. It appears the service principal doesn't have rights to read from that subscription.

Go to portal and find your `subscription`, click on `Access Control (IAM)` and then click on `Add role assignment` with `correspond service principal` which you use to acquire token.

After you have given successful permission, refresh and try again.

Comment: There is no **Azure Resource Management** available in **Add role assignment**. Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you refer my step?

Comment: Yes I am adding access to subscription and I got only **Azure Resource Topology** in search. Not the one you mentioned.

Comment: Could you provide the code about `AcquireTokenAsync`?

Comment: If you acquire token use service principle with clientId, you need to add that service principle into subscription.

Comment: Hi @Joey thanks for your hint about adding service principle to the subscription. That helps me to resolve the problem!

Comment: Actually, I have created AD and register app in it. That app needs to be registered against the subscription. That part I was missing while configuration.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same error while running,

```
az aks get-credentials --resource-group myResourceGroup --name myAKSCluster
```

I did this shortly after `az login`.
Problem was I haven't set my subscription properly so what I had to do was run,

```
az account set --subscription your-subscription-id
```

After that `az aks get-credentials` worked fine, the error was gone and you will get an output like,

*`Merged "myAKSCluster" as current context in C:\Users\UserName\.kube\config`*

Comment: spent a whole day troubleshooting what I was doing wrong, didnt figure out I hadnt set the sub....sigh. Thanks brother.

Answer (score 2):

**Since `Azure` can be really complicated, I will try to break it down so anyone can understand.**

*Everyone are welcome to modify this post to the better as I am probably not 100% clear either.*

**Account Directories**

When you create an Azure account, it creates a `directory` (Default Directory), a directory is called a `Tenant`, you can have multiple such `directories`, I think you can even have separate login credentials for each, it is like an entirely separate organization, each `directory` has its `subscriptions`, `resource groups`, `resources`/`apps`, etc.

[image: Your account directories]
**Azure Active Directory**

Each directory has its own `Azure Active Directory` listing all its `Users`, `Groups`, and `Applications`, that are the `clients`/`objects` going to be accessing or performing actions on the `Resources` within this `Directory` (tenant).

In this case it's your programmed `app` that's gonna execute tasks on your Azure `resources`, and in order to do this, the `client` (your app) needs to have proper `permission` to perform the specific `action` (whatever action you wanna do), directly permitted to execute it on the specific `resource`.

[image]

First you need to create a `client` - which is the process of registering your `app`, at `Azure Active Directory` > `App Registrations` click `New Registration`, here you register your program `app` as a `client`/`object` that you want to use for accessing your Azure `resources`, give it a name MyApp, click `Register`, you will get an `Application (client) ID` which you gonna use in your code as the `client ID`, this `app` is now a `User`/`Service Principal` in your `Azure AD (active directory)`, it now remains to give it permission for the actions you wanna perform on some `resource`.

Go to the `Resource`/`Resource group` (`App Service`/`Database`/`VM`), or to the `Subscription` (which would give it permission to access all `resources` within the entire `subscription`), click on `Access control (IAM)` > `Add` > `Add role assignment`.

[image: Access control (IAM)]

- In the 'Add role assignment' screen, select the role action, in your case `Reader`.
- Go to the `Members` tab and here we're going to select the `Service principal` (the app that you just registered).
- Click on "Select members", you'll see the AD users, but by default, you will not see AD `apps` that you registered, you need to search for them by their name, enter the name you've just given 'MyApp'.
- Select it from the list below and click `Select` at the bottom
- Finish the Assignment...

Follow the clicks by the numbers in the image below.
[image: Add role assignment]

You should now refresh your credentials in your app, by re-executing the code that authorizes the `client`, make sure you use the correct `client-ID` of the `app` that you registered in Azure, for some permissions, it may take a few minutes for the permissions to be updated, once it is, you should be good to go.

If you see the `AuthorizationFailed` again, check if it's still the failed for same `action`, as there might be another `action` you need to assign for the `principal` in order to achieve your output.

I hope this is going to help somebody... Good luck!

***Links that might be helpful:***

- [Steps to generate a new client secret and link it to key-vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/industry/training-services/microsoft-community-training/frequently-asked-questions/generate-new-clientsecret-link-to-key-vault)
- [Create an Azure Active Directory application and service principal that can access resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Initially, I went ahead and added to my user the "Web Plan Contributor" role, as it is the one that should handle those things. Nothing changed - I still had this error.

What turned actual problem turned out to be is a **wrong resource group**... Turns out I copied some old script where WebAppPlans were in separate RG, and I was searching the app plan there. Completely missleading error. I guess it will bring up the same error message even if the App Plan simply doesn't exist.