# Release pipeline does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Web/sites/config/list/action'

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I have a DevOps release pipeline pushing out (via CLI on a VM) to a dev resource group happily. When I add a stage pushing to an identical QA resource group I get the below.

ERROR: (AuthorizationFailed) The client '' with object id '' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Web/sites/config/list/action' over scope '/subscriptions//resourceGroups//providers/Microsoft.Web/sites//config/publishingcredentials' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials.

Is there a place I should be looking at first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is due to the service principa(in azure devops, typically is 'service connection') doesn't have correct role/permission on the target resource.

1. Please find your service connection in Project settings.
   [image]
2. Click `Manage Service Principal` which will redirect you to the Application Registration of the Service Principal. All you need to do here is copy the name (the default format is `<account>-<prject>-<GUID>`).
3. Go back and click `Manage service connection roles` which will redirect you to the IAM blade of the Azure Subscription. Here you need to assign a role to the service principal of which you copied the name of in the previous step. you can add it as subscription owner/contributor role on the target subscription simply.

You can check similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58319749/14996050).